# SQL Server: Include only a percentage of rows based on type

Tags: sql, sql-server, limit, percentage

I have  a table of questions that are typed: `Select One`, `True False`, `Select All` 
I am trying to write a query that will return a certain number of questions, while limiting one of the types to be a specific percentage of types returned.

Example:

```
SELECT QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionType
FROM Question
WHERE/HAVING --limit QuestionTypeID = 4 to be only 10% of total returned
```

My original thoughts were to pull the queries separately

```
SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionType
FROM Question
WHERE QuestionTypeID <> 4
UNION ALL
SELECT QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionType
FROM Question
WHERE QuestionTypeID = 4
```

However it seems that there is probably a more efficient way of computing this.

---

**EDIT:**

Let me clarify what I am trying to accomplish... I need to return 90 % a mixture of the other types of question and only 10% of the type 4.

I need the results to be randomized so I have been using `SET ROWCOUNT` and `ORDER BY NEWID()`

I can use subqueries but am unsure of the way I would go about using `SET ROWCOUNT` in a subquery...at this point it seems temp tables are required but if there is a better way please let me know...

What I have so far... *with temp tables*

```
DECLARE @ReturnPercent [int] --variable that holds percentage for bottom questions
DECLARE @ReturnCount [int] --variable that holds how many questions I'd like returned

CREATE TABLE #Temp1(
        QuestionID [int], 
        QuestionText [nvarchar](256), 
        QuestionTypeID [int]
);

DECLARE @TOP [int] = @ReturnCount-CAST(@ReturnCount*@ReturnPercent AS INT);
DECLARE @BOTTOM [int] = CAST(@ReturnCount(@ReturnPercent AS INT);

SET ROWCOUNT @TOP
INSERT INTO #Temp1(QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionTypeID)
SELECT QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionTypeID
FROM Question
WHERE QuestionTypeID <> 4
ORDER BY NEWID()
SET ROWCOUNT 0

SET ROWCOUNT @BOTTOM
INSERT INTO #Temp1(QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionTypeID)
SELECT QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionTypeID
FROM Question
WHERE QuestionTypeID = 4
ORDER BY NEWID()
SET ROWCOUNT 0

--Query to join them with other data(omitted) 
SET ROWCOUNT @ReturnCount
SELECT a.QuestionID, a.QuestionText, a.QuestionTypeID
FROM #Temp1 a
JOIN --OTHER TABLES FOR FULL QUERY
ORDER BY NEWID()
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

Comment: (MS) SQL Server - from the title and the `SELECT TOP 10 PERCENT`

Comment: @Cameron: Since `SQL Server` is a trademark of an MS product, the `(MS)` isn't necessary. It's like `Internet Explorer` obviously doesn't mean `Mozilla Firefox`. :-)

Comment: I was responding to a comment which asked the DBMS. It was deleted. The parentheses are there because the 'MS' isn't necessary :).

Answer (score 0):

The union all is quite possibly the most efficient way to do this.

There is an efficient way to assign a row number to all rows:

```
SELECT row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
```

However, I don't think this is efficient if you add a partition clause.  If this were efficient and if you had an index on question id, you could use:

```
select q.QuestionID, q.QuestionText, q.QuestionType
from (select QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionType,
             row_number() over (partition by QuestionId order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Question
     ) q join
     (select QuestionId, count(*) as cnt
      From Question
      group by Questionid
     ) qsum
     q.questionid = qsum.questionid
where questionid <> 4 or seqnum*1.0/cnt <= 0.1
```

(The idea is that the group by would be satisfied by the index, the join would be very cheap, and the row_number() efficient.)

However, I think, the union all is probably faster.

Hmmm, now that I think about it, you could get pretty far with an approximation:

```
select q.QuestionID, q.QuestionText, q.QuestionType
from (select QuestionID, QuestionText, QuestionType,
             row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum
      from Question
     ) q
where mod(seqnum, 10) <> 0 and questionid <> 4 or
      mod(seqnum, 10) = 0 and questionid = 4
```

This takes about 90% of the rows where questionid <> 4 and about 10% where questionid = 4.  This should be quite efficient, since the row_number() in this phrasing assigns a sequential number with no sorting or partitioning.